# Why can't I cd into a directory with a user not owner group

Tags: permissions, directory

I created a user on my server specifically for an external application. I want the application to be able to ssh into the user account and cd into a directory. However, it keeps saying permission denied when I try to do that. I set the permissions on the folder to "Access," thinking this will do the trick.

Here is a screenshot of the folder permissions :

[image]

What gives?

Comment: What are the permissions of the parent folder?

Answer (score 8):

Your parent folder must be readable (in a sense) too.

For example, I have a folder `test`, with another folder, `test2` inside of it. Permissions are as such:

```
drwxrwx---   3 kazwolfe kazwolfe     4096 Dec 30 13:18 test/
drwxrwxr-x   2 kazwolfe nogroup      4096 Dec 30 13:18 test/test2
```

As you can see, the `nobody` user (member of `nogroup`) has permissions for `test/test2`, but it can't `cd` into it:

```
cd: test/test2: Permission denied
```

Why? Simply put, because the `nobody` user does not have rights to read from `test`. Therefore, they are blocked from accessing any subdirectories or subfiles of `test`, even if they have permission!

In order to resolve this, I need to ensure that the execute bit (`chmod a+x test`) on any parent folder is set so I can traverse the folder(s) needed:

```
┌─[13:35:22]─[nobody@ArcticWolf]
└──> ~ $ cd test
┌─[13:35:24]─[nobody@ArcticWolf]
└──> test $ ll
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
┌─[✗]─[13:35:27]─[nobody@ArcticWolf]
└──> test $ cd test2
┌─[13:35:31]─[nobody@ArcticWolf]
└──> test2 $ touch hello
┌─[13:35:34]─[nobody@ArcticWolf]
└──> test2 $ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 kazwolfe nogroup  4096 Dec 30 13:35 ./
drwxrwx--x 3 kazwolfe kazwolfe 4096 Dec 30 13:22 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody   nogroup     0 Dec 30 13:35 hello
```

Note that setting the execute bit on a folder allows a user to access anything inside the folder *that they have permission for, and know exists*. See [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21263/56507) for a more in-depth view of permissions on folders.